# I am getting following error while executing a master page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am getting following error while executing a master page.

```
 'WingtipToys.SiteMaster' is not allowed here because it does not extend class 'System.Web.UI.MasterPage'.

Line 1:  <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="WingtipToys.SiteMaster" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. 'WingtipToys.SiteMaster' should be inherited from 'System.Web.UI.MasterPage' class
2. Make sure that you do not have compilation errors in 'WingtipToys.SiteMaster'